# macOS Finder extension?

Tags: macos, finder

I wonder if it is possible to write extensions for the current macOS Finder app. I'd like to have an extension that features a text terminal subwindow running a shell session below the directory contents of a Finder window.

Any ideas if this is possible at all (in a "legal" way)? I do know of the Finder Sync extension type as well as those listed in the [Extensibility PG](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/).

Comment: how about just creating a new service in _Automator_?

Comment: @holex I already have a Finder toolbar button to open a Terminal.app session with the current working directory set to the path of the Finder window. I'd rather have the shell window integrated into the Finder window.

Answer (score 0):

Working on Catalina....

Finder extensions still work fine. I don't have the same requirement to put some sort of output INSIDE the finder window, but we provide an auxiliary window outside. Apple has always seemed to be cautious about access to finder. You can communicate with it just fine from another app (sandboxed or not) through the Notification system. The usual entitlements for file access also apply.